# repeated measures poisson? R

Tags: r, regression

have searched and found similar qs to mine but still confused on how to approach this..

i have data (`dat`) of the following form

| favorite veg | group1 | group2 | Avg IQ | Avg # of Siblings | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| potato | 100 | 123 | 115 | 4 | 2001 |
| carrot | 198 | 156 | 120 | 6 | 2001 |
| potato | 196 | 150 | 130 | 2 | 2002 |
| carrot | 127 | 111 | 112 | 3 | 2002 |
| potato | 201 | 100 | 118 | 3 | 2003 |
| carrot | 178 | 98 | 121 | 4 | 2003 |

Lets say (barring everything that may or may not make sense about the data) I am trying to perform a repeated measures Poisson regression w/ the number of people endorsing a veg in group 1 as my outcome, and avg IQ & # of siblings as a predictors.

is the code below an appropriate way to achieve this? thank you all!!

```
regress <- glm(group1 ~ `favorite veg`*Year + `Avg IQ` + 
             `Avg # of Siblings`, data = dat, 
              family = "poisson")
```

Comment: what is the repeated sampling unit?

Comment: @BenBolker sorry but not sure what this means 

Comment: a repeated measures analysis means that there is some level of grouping for which you have measured the same individuals/units/blocks/whatever more than once (not necessarily the same level of replication for each group). If you're only using group1, this doesn't necessarily sound like a repeated measures analysis ...

Comment: would it become one if i'm using group 2 as well? in the real dataset i'm using i'm doing this, but thought i would have to consider group 2 as the outcome variable in a second regression. what would be the appropriate way to do this w/ repeated measures?

Comment: From @Kirsten: I am a little curious about what you actually want to answer?

Based on the comment above it seems like you are looking for a way to make the analysis a repeated measures analysis, maybe because of an exercise?

If you are not sure about the model approach or the question you want to ask, try to elaborate relevant information in more details.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little curious about what you actually want to answer?

Based on the comment above it seems like you are looking for a way to make the analysis a repeated measures analysis, maybe because of an exercise?

If you are not sure about the model approach or the question you want to ask, try to elaborate relevant information in more details.

Sorry for making this an answer.